# How to add storage using Volume in a Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have a spring boot application and I want to start it on a docker container. However, I want to persist data, so I do not have to rebuild image to see the changes I made to RestAPI.

My docker file

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY . /usr/src/

RUN mvn clean install

WORKDIR /usr/src/target

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "SecurityAndDocker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080:8080
```

Image build is ok

Running `docker run -p 8080:8080 image-name` works perfectly fine

How would I attach a volume to this application?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the docker docs for volume `mount` ing.

Comment: Note that even if you do attach a volume, it's there to hold _data_, and you'll have to rebuild your jar file outside of Docker space to rebuild it in any case.  Re-running `docker build` isn't going to be a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

you can mount the volume, while running the container.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name <container-name> --mount source=myvol2,target=/app <image-name>
```

you can also read the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Feel free to ask in case you found any issue.

Comment: i do not know what to type into target=/app
My image name is docker-security
Volume name is vol-spring
How would final statement be ?

Comment: I tried 
```docker run  -p 8080:8080 --name stack --mount source=vol-spring,target=/usr/src docker-security```
   and    
```docker run  -p 8080:8080 --name stack --mount source=vol-spring,target=/app docker-security```
but still does not work.

Comment: I do not recieve error, the application starts but changes made in restAPI and restarting the container are not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want the target directory  to be extracted out in a volume from your custom image's container.
use `VOLUME` keyword to specify the directory. 
Your dockerfile should go like this.

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY . /usr/src/

RUN mvn clean install
VOLUME /usr/src/target

WORKDIR/usr/src/target
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "SecurityAndDocker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080:8080
```

The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If you want to save the working directory just add VOLUME  in your dockerfile.

Comment: does not persist data